# WebStorm - can't see the path of the method definition, when it has several definitions (implementations)

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Just updated from WebStorm 2019.1.4 to 2019.3.3 and when I'm trying to open method definitions, I can't see the path of definition.

Currently, I have some methods with the same names, but they're available in the different files/folders. So when I'm trying to navigate to those methods, I need to see, which exact method I'm opening.

Could someone help? How can I configure it?

Screenshot of 2019.1.4
[image: Screenshot of 2019.1.4 example]

Screenshot of 2019.3.3:
[image: Screenshot of 2019.3.3 example]

Answer (score 1):

[WEB-41072](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41072) is fixed in WS2020.1; you can try the [EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/) to see if it works for you